# How to extract text from "data-at"?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** the Sephora website for the perfume page.  When I am trying to get the Brand name, I have had trouble accessing the text that is after the “data-at”, so here is my attempt but I am not sure why it is not working...

```
for container in perfume_containers:
# The brand
   brand = container.find('span', attrs={'class':'css-ktoumz'})['data-at']
   brands.append(brand)
```

[image]

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value of any tag that you successfully selected using class filter or any other filter, then assuming you are using `BeautifulSoup` you can access the value of this tag using `.text` attribute

example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.sephora.com/shop/perfume"
url = (url)

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

print(soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'css-ktoumz'}).get('data-at')) # will print sku_item_brand
print(soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'css-ktoumz'}).text) # will print CHANEL
```

Comment: Thank you Kareem!  It worked! So is that mean instead of using ['data-at'] to access the data, I should use .get('data-at')? And also, for defining the variable soup, I used "soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')" instead of the way you defined it, is that another reason that makes mine not working?

Comment: sorry for the delay , using ```.get``` serves the same output as ```[]``` but ```.get``` returns empty if there is no such value while `[]` accessor raises an exception so I prefer ```.get``` in such cases. 
I alway use xml parser, you can check the docs for different parse trees produced by each parser and their cons/pros, maybe the parser you used yields different results but I'm not sure it would miss such a class filter. 
Mostly scraping will bring you a alot of errors due to missing values, I reccomend you use a debugger like ```ipdb```  to make sure you understand whats 'wrong

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much Kareem!